# How do I make my hamburger menu icon be on top of my banner image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues making the hamburger icon be on top of the banner image. I've tried adjusting the z-index, setting the nav background-color to transparent, and placing the background image in the header instead of the banner section. I don't know what other steps to take. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
/*Nav*/
header {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #567E3A;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #7F8C8D;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.burger {
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}



/*Banner*/

#banner {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dboauovcs/image/upload/c_scale,w_2000/v1521182602/camp3_xhp0d9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.banner-text {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text h1 {
  margin: 2em 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav id="main-nav" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="#">Destinations</a>
                <a href="#">Accomidation</a>
                <a href="#">Stories</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <span class="burger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    </header>



    <section id="banner">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Book Today</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
/*Nav*/
header {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #567E3A;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #7F8C8D;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.burger {
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}



/*Banner*/

#banner {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dboauovcs/image/upload/c_scale,w_2000/v1521182602/camp3_xhp0d9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.banner-text {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text h1 {
  margin: 2em 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav id="main-nav" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="#">Destinations</a>
                <a href="#">Accomidation</a>
                <a href="#">Stories</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <span class="burger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    </header>



    <section id="banner">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Book Today</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

A little explanation on what I've done here (presuming this is the treatment you are looking for):  By [positioning the hamburger as `absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), we pull it completely out of the static layout flow, so other elements ignore its existence when positioning.  The element's location can then be controlled with [left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), [right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right), [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) and [bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom), and will position itself relative to the first ancestor element positioned absolutely, or the `body` if no element is positioned absolutely.  You'll probably want to consider dialing in the positioning a bit with these attributes, as you might not want to rely on the browser to calculate its position with defaults.

Comment: Always add little explanation for the answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, you're right :)  I was hoping to get a reply from OP to make sure this was actually what he was looking for before I gave the full explanation, but I'll go ahead and pop it in now.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("main-nav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
/*Nav*/
header {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #567E3A;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #7F8C8D;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.burger {
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}



/*Banner*/

#banner {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dboauovcs/image/upload/c_scale,w_2000/v1521182602/camp3_xhp0d9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.banner-text {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text h1 {
  margin: 2em 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav id="main-nav" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="#">Destinations</a>
                <a href="#">Accomidation</a>
                <a href="#">Stories</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <span class="burger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    </header>



    <section id="banner">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Book Today</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```